# VS2017: Create offline installer after installation

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I installed visual studio by executing `vs_Professional.exe` downloaded from https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/professional/, this downloads and installed program correctly. But now i want to do the same installation on another PC can i reuse the intaller files stored in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages`?

Answer (score 0):

Installers can not be created from those already installed.
Please download again.
There is a detailed explanation on this page.
[Install Visual Studio 2017 on low bandwidth or unreliable network environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-vs-inconsistent-quality-network)

Please replace vs_community.exe in the explanation with vs_professional.exe and process it.

```
from: vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout
to:   vs_professional.exe --layout c:\vs2017layout
```

Comment: It is stated "Do not use the Download all, then install feature to create a local cache that you intend to transfer to another computer. It's not designed to work that way."   Does that mean, the offline installer is not re-usable ?

Comment: The local cache and the offline installer are probably different things. The local cache should be downloaded in advance for quick installation and update to the exact PC it is running on, not transfer it to another PC. The note is about how to use the local cache and doesn't say anything about the offline installer.

Comment: Right, that explains. In that case, your prposed statement should create an offline installer which is re-usable ?  I will give it a try today. I kind of remember doing it in past though.

Comment: that's right. My answer is to download a set of offline installer packages that can be applied to other PCs in the specified directory.